# Filling up <td> in PHP table from array

Tags: php, loops, html-table

I am having difficulty trying to display data into  `<td>` columns properly. I have the table headers and first table column working properly. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to display the other data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

from what I know, this is how you fill a simple 2x2 array

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<tr>';

    // create first td (column name)
    echo '<td>';
    echo $month[$row];
    echo '</td>';

    // create the rest td (data value)
    foreach($columns as $column){
        echo '<td>';
        echo $data[$row][$column];
        echo '</td'>; 
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

your rows will be cities name and months name as columns

so my solution

```
//start table
echo '<table>';

//first row
echo '<tr>';
    //first header
    echo '<th> Month </th>';
    //rest of headers
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
         echo  '<th>' .$data['series'][$i]['name']. '</th>'; 
    }
echo '</tr>';

//rest of rows 
for ($x = 0; $x < 12; $x++){
echo '<tr>';
    //first column
    echo '</td>';
    echo $data['categories'][$x];
    echo '</td>';

    //rest of columns
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        echo '<td>';
        echo $data['series'][$i]['data'][$x];
        echo('</td>');
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: @skoteinos i see that your month columns `<td>` are not wrapped in `<tr>`, please check the table hierarchy. one `<tr>` must contain multiple `<td>`s, and no `<td>` standing alone

Comment: pls check my edited answer if you want first column of each row to be months name

Answer (score 0):

You are having many mistakes of syntax. Echo does not require parenthesis. Each cell needs a td tag.

Also it is ambiguous what kind of format the array that you are using have. Depending on that the solution might come out.

Still, here is a proposal. You may need to modify it depending on the organization of the array.

```
<?php
//get json data
$data = json_decode($output, true);

//start table
echo '<table><tr><th> Month </th>';
//table headers
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    echo  '<th>' . $data['series'][$i]['name'] . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

//column of months
$number = 0;
foreach ($data['categories'] as $value) 
{
    foreach($data['series'] as $inst)
    {
        $month_data = $month_data . "<td>" . $inst['data'][$number] . "</td>";
    };
    echo "<tr><td>$value</td>" . $month_data . "</tr>";
    $number++;

    unset($month_data);
};
echo '</table>';
?>
```

The part that I called $month_data will change depending on how the array is organised. To see how it is organised use this:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```